# how to align pricing tables and center them with bootstrap and scss

Tags: html, sass

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Odaberi Paket</h1>
            </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div> 
            <div class="col-xl-3 cl-md-3">
                <div class="pricing-table">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="controle-header panel-heading panel-heading-landing">
                        <span class="price-value">150<span class="currency">EUR</span></span>
                            <h3 class="panel-title panel-title-landing">Pocetni Paket</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-landing">
                            <table class="table">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor <br>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer panel-footer-landing">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Odaberi</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <img class="saksijica" src="np-assets/images/saksijica.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 cl-md-3">
            <img class="cat" src="np-assets/images/maca.png"> 
                <div class="pricing-table">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="controle-header panel-heading panel-heading-landing">
                        <span class="price-value">150<span class="currency">EUR+DODACI</span></span>
                            <h3 class="panel-title panel-title-landing">Pro Paket</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-landing">
                            <table class="table">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor <br>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer panel-footer-landing">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Odaberi</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Newbie here.
    I have a problem aligning pricing tables and centering them, and on top of all that there should be a picture on the down left corner of left pricing table and on the top of the right should be also a picture.
    Here is my code someone help me to mension there should be no padding between them.

Comment: Please add your CSS to this question, as it's pretty difficult to help with styling otherwise!

Comment: You're not using `<table>` correctly, check this out https://html.com/tables/